# Link with dynamic variable

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get a link to generate a dynamic query string. The list is rendering the record within a map loop, but I can't seem to render the variable inside the `Link` tag. In the browser it shows `{record.idea_uniqueid}`.

```
<Link to="/searchIdeaDetail?IUI={record.idea_uniqueid}">
  <ListItem>
    <Avatar><WorkIcon /></Avatar>
    <ListItemText primary={record.ideaName} secondary={record.lkpEmail} />
  </ListItem>
</Link>
```

Comment: use templete literal or pass url by const/variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write like following:

```
<Link to={`/searchIdeaDetail?IUI=${record.idea_uniqueid}`}>
  <ListItem>
    <Avatar><WorkIcon /></Avatar>
    <ListItemText primary={record.ideaName} secondary={record.lkpEmail} />
  </ListItem>
</Link>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thanks, it's working.. looks like you cant use ' or " , but ` does work. My keyboard doesn't have that character... so I had to copy / paste off the screen :)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<Link to="/searchIdeaDetail?IUI={record.idea_uniqueid}">
```

to

```
<Link to={`/searchIdeaDetail?IUI=${record.idea_uniqueid}`}>
```

Comment: Thanks @kiarashws , it's working.. looks like you cant use ' or " , but ` does work. My keyboard doesn't have that character... so I had to copy / paste off the screen :)

Comment: You're welcome :) , please care to check as answer if it worked for your problem.